# Bug with too long text in html tag <kbd>

Tags: bug, html-entities

If text in the `<kbd>` html tag is too long it isn't transferred to the next line, but gets out further:

Like screenshot:

[image: screenshot of bug]

Like HTML:

<kbd>vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvveeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy llllllllllllllllllooooooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggg ttteeeexxxxtttt.</kbd>

*(Sorry for machine translation)*